# Authentication failed - OWIN - OAuth - Webapi 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-authorization

I have created a WebAPI 2.0 service and a Windows Forms client. I can create a valid token request by the client.

But when I try to use that bearer token for accessing the WebAPI I get the following error:

Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware Error: 0 : Authentication failed
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey, KeyId: 'djaskjd', InternalId: 'djaskjd'. , KeyId: djaskjd
'.
Number of keys in TokenValidationParameters: '16'.
Number of keys in Configuration: '0'.
Matched key was in 'TokenValidationParameters'.

Server Validation:

```
     public partial class Startup
        {
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
    
                ConfigureAuth(app);
            }
    
            private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
            {
              public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
              {
            app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Audience"],
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"],
                TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidIssuers = new[] { "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[\"Tenant\"]}/v2.0" }
                }
            });
        }            }
        }
```

Client Authentication

```
 private static void GetAuth()
        {

            autth = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
                    .WithRedirectUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient")
                    .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, Tenant)
                    .Build();
        }
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Please put your token [here](https://jwt.io) and check out the signature is alright first. Looks like it's invalid token that was signed by invalid key that the authority can't validate. Maybe you should check if there is any typo in the token when you use it.

Comment: Hi hina10531, I already checked the token. The token itself is correct. The signature can't be decrypted because it is encrypted by HS256. It that is maybe the same error that I get from the service. I can see that the key is downloaded by owin. But it is not used.

Answer (score 0):

The client code was correct. Just the scopes was not correct. You have to use the API of the client that references the server / backend.